# How to check ETH contract deposit?

Tags: ether

I want to check ETH contract deposit.

ETH contract deposit : (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc4ae4e2444e91b02633cc771468585c954cc444e300ddceb659776287a4bdd39)

```
{
  "blockHash": "0x065e3b474eb1b099a462e5043b906130bf27ed487cc0177a7571b1c059f0bf62",
  "blockNumber": "0x6db0a6",
  "from": "0x8fa8af91c675452200e49b4683a33ca2e1a34e42",
  "gas": "0x30d40",
  "gasPrice": "0xdf8475800",
  "hash": "0xc4ae4e2444e91b02633cc771468585c954cc444e300ddceb659776287a4bdd39",
  "input": "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",
  "nonce": "0xf83",
  "r": "0x4101a528c1a21c320b4270ef42845bb35dcc17dab4fd9036769a3c022ba0343d",
  "s": "0x1e9727d23d54b45b966893cdc13cf16dbaf3c90706cf52cfd2a2d832a298d22b",
  "to": "0x3fbe1f8fc5ddb27d428aa60f661eaaab0d2000ce",
  "transactionIndex": "0xc",
  "v": "0x25",
  "value": "0x0"
}
```

Can i get the toAddress and amount from input? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have the contract ABI you can determine the function being called from the input.

If you do not have the ABI you can inspect the first four bytes to try to identify the function being called.

In this particular the first 4 bytes are `0x39125215`. Consulting a database of functions signatures www.4byte.directory we obtain.

```
sendMultiSig(address,uint256,bytes,uint256,uint256,bytes)
```

Searching it seems the contract is an instance of this repository https://github.com/BitGo/eth-multisig-v2/blob/master/contracts/WalletSimple.sol

Assuming the contract is correct you can use its ABI to determine the parameters of the transaction.

```
  /**
   * Execute a multi-signature transaction from this wallet using 2 signers: one from msg.sender and the other from ecrecover.
   * Sequence IDs are numbers starting from 1. They are used to prevent replay attacks and may not be repeated.
   *
   * @param toAddress the destination address to send an outgoing transaction
   * @param value the amount in Wei to be sent
   * @param data the data to send to the toAddress when invoking the transaction
   * @param expireTime the number of seconds since 1970 for which this transaction is valid
   * @param sequenceId the unique sequence id obtainable from getNextSequenceId
   * @param signature see Data Formats
   */
  function sendMultiSig(
      address toAddress,
      uint value,
      bytes data,
      uint expireTime,
      uint sequenceId,
      bytes signature
  ) public onlySigner {
```

In the case you are not able to identify the function call the final case is to use low level functions like geth's [debug_traceTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction) or parity's [trace_transaction](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-trace-module#trace_transaction).

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question.
is the all of Ethereum internal transation using sendMultiSig func??
if that true, can I get a `toAddress ` and `volume` using parsing `input` data?

Comment: @HeesuCheon No, internal transactions do not appear in the transaction. You need to use `debug_traceTransaction` from geth or `trace_rawTransaction` from parity.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` variable doesn't encode the transaction, it'd the tx data sent with the transaction. The `to` and a`value` are in receipt you posted, the last property and the 4th from the last.

Comment: Thanks! but I want to get internal transaction. I said it wrong.. sorry